# is there a resizing animation for SVG element

Tags: svg, svg-animate

What I have is some svg element produced by JS code on the fly such as lines and circles that consist of some geometry figure, what I want to achieve is to try to rescale the figure continuously using svg animation feature. I mean of course I could recompute the coordinates of each point of the line and center point of the circle and start from there but that would be a too tedious solution how can I do better?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a `<g>` element and then give that `<g>` a transform attribute like transform="scale(1)" and animate that using a child `<animateTransform>` element. Something like this perhaps...

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform"
 attributeType="XML" type="scale" from="1" to="3"
 additive="sum" begin="1s" dur="5s" fill="freeze"/>
```